# Removing a String Only

Tags: jquery, string

I am trying to remove a string of text (via Jquery) that does not have any tag except for it's parent and have only been able to remove the entire thing.

I need to keep the  tag (inside the Span, and keep that too) as I want to keep the icon but remove the text, example below. I want to remove 'SIGN OUT'.

I tried using this but it removes the entire  code.

```js
(function($) {
  $("a:contains('SIGN OUT')").remove("a:contains(' SIGN OUT')");
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="header-block header-link" href="account/signout" rel="nofollow">
  <span class="hidden-xd">
    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i><br/>
  </span> SIGN OUT
</a>
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: you could put the text in another `span` so it can be easily found and then clear the text with `.html()` . `<span class='btn-text'>SIGN OUT</span>` then `$('a .btn-text:contains("SIGN OUT")').html('')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is alter the html of the `a`. jQuery has a function for this - `.html()`.

In the code example below, I have used this to assign the existing html of the `a` after the text `SIGN OUT` has been removed:

```js
(function($) {
  $("a:contains('SIGN OUT')").html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace('SIGN OUT', '');
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="header-block header-link" href="account/signout" rel="nofollow">
  <span class="hidden-xd">
    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i><br/>
  </span>
  SIGN OUT
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

If I was to remove more items that had different words, do I add the each separately or can I add more to that code?

It must of been .html function I was looking for.

Comment: The other issue I am having it flickers up when page loads and then disaappears. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the [node type](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp). You can try something like this

```js
(function($) {
  $(".header-link").contents().filter(function() {
    return (this.nodeType == 3 && this.textContent.includes("SIGN OUT"));
  }).remove();
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="header-block header-link" href="account/signout" rel="nofollow">
  <span class="hidden-xd">
<i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
<br/>Other content
</span> SIGN OUT
</a>
```